# Спарсить описание go-colly

Tags: golang

Пробую спарсить описание(Description) с web страницы, но не пойму, как до него добраться ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
c.OnHTML(".short", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
    pg.Name = e.ChildText("h2.short-cat")
    pg.Link = e.ChildAttr("a", "href")
    pg.Rating = e.ChildText("a.orating_res")
    pg.Description = e.ChildText("div.short-text full-text video-box clearfix")

    slPG = append(slPG, pg)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указывать начало, остальное автоматом найдёт

```
e.ChildText("div.short-text")
```